# Where are the data for attached files stored

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone know how the screen's attached file functionality is accomplished - either whether they're stored (as BLOBS? - and if so, which table?) or any type of information as to how the link is stored in the database?

As an example, the Bills and Adjustments screen -> Files icon at the top.  I can't find any BLC code or even page source code javascript that would show how this is being done or where the storage is taking place (either on the web server or as a BLOB in the db)

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `UploadFile` contains the list of files
- `NoteDoc` links the `NoteId` field to the `FileId`
- `UploadFileRevision` contains the actual binary data in the `Data` column for each revision of the files. If you use an external storage provider (S3, Azure Blob Storage or Box.com), the data won't be in the record but instead stored externally

Comment: Thanks so much, Gabriel!   ;D